# Which one library is better for reading PDF, EPUB & html in Android?

Tags: android, pdf, epub, ebook-reader

I wana to create a App that should into App read ebooks with pdf, epub, html formats. that work familar to Ebook-reader but not exactly.

Which one library is better for reading PDF in Android?

For PDF: iText, jPedal, Mupdf, Pdfbox

For Epub: Is there any library except epublib???

Finally html: ???

Which one is free and can customize it?

Comment: Did you find your answer!?